# How can I see a graph of Google Play referrals on Google Analytics?

Tags: google, google-analytics, analytics, android

I am able to see the referrals in the referral flow section. but I cannot find them again anywhere else.

I need to see stats about each referral over time. Any way to so this?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Report, which you'd like to use Acquisition -> Sources -> Google Play, uses UTMs for tracking referrals.

You've got hint from GA (mouseover on question mark next to "(direct) / none") that this source contains also referrals, because you don't tag links.

You couldn't look in your historical data, but if you add UTMs, you will track a future data.

Comment: add utm to what? these are organic referrals. Sorry I do not understand what you mean in the second and 3rd paragraph please explain.

Comment: You can tag also organic referrals. Example: http://example.com?utm_medium=referral&utm_source=referralsite&utm_campaign=apps . UTMs could be used for whole organic traffic

Comment: I am not getting you. I want to see details of the referrals over time. one of the referrals is "organic" this means people clicking my app link from google play. how can I put a utm in google play? i cant

Comment: If user comes to google play directly, it is direct. If comes to app profile in google play from SERP, it will be "google / organic" (i think). If you have some links on your site, in some blog posts or forum, you need to use UTMs to track a source.